# Fuelphp framework проблема при установке

Tags: php, установка

хотел попробовать фреймворк fuelphp, но при установке возникла проблема, ввожу адрес `localhost/fuel/public` и вижу такой текст:

> Composer is not installed.
>
> Please run "php composer.phar update" in the root to install Composer.

В интернете толком ничего не нашел. Если кто сталкивался с таким, то отпишитесь пожалуйста как это решить

Comment: Есть скайп? Мой - crazy.jump. но вряд ли найдешь, лучше свой напиши. Пиши, помогу все поставить.

Comment: > я ввел в консоли cd c:\WebServers\home\localhost\www\fuelphp\ затем php composer.phar update и получил:

git'a разве не стоит? http://www.git-scm.com/ - устанавливаете git, в переменную среды path после установки нужно добавить путь до исполняемых файлов git. Примерно так:

set path=%path%;c:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\

Comment: благодарю за помощь ! Запустил, на днях попробую по работать с Fuel. А ты что нибудь писал на Fuelphp?

Comment: С FuelPHP не работал, иначе бы в один коммент отписал как его поставить. Но я работал с CodeIgniter, Zend 1/2 - если мне не изменяет память, то FuelPHP именно от CI ответвился, так что, я думаю, что они впринципе должны быть похожи.

Comment: сорь если уже написали, но судя по ошибке или не установлен composer или его исполняемый файл не добавлен в PATH

сам composer можно найти тут http://getcomposer.org/

если установлен уже то (судя по пути у тебя Windows) нужно зайти в свойства компьютера "System properties" > кнопка "Environment Variables" > в окошке "System variables" найди в списке "PATH" > двойной клик, в конце строки поставь ";" и полный путь к директории куда был установлен composer

сорь если слишком подробно, но может еще у кого будет такая проблема

Comment: благодарю, хотя уже разобрался. Подробный ответ не помешает действительно. В сети я ничего толкового не нашел, так что хоть тут будет решение проблемы

Андрей, только жаль, что в Fuelphp нет столько готовых хелперов как в CI, придется самому вес расписывать. Сейчас сам CI пользуюсь, взялся за него так как отличная документация учитываю что это для меня первый фреймворк ну и установка простейшая, а так же много встроенных плюшек которые экономят время разработки приложения

Comment: Есть мнение, что CI это лишь (прошу прощения за грубость) "высер" - некое промежуточное состояние кода между openSource проектом и коммерческой CMS ExpressionEngine. По крайней мере разрабатывался для ellislab для этого.

Answer (score 2):

Ну ошибка вам говорит сама за себя: "Composer is not installed". Если контур под виндой работает, то вам [сюда](http://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md#installation-windows), если под linux то там же, чуть выше. Composer - это расширение для php для устранения зависимостей между веб-приложениями. После установки в командной строке выполнить:

> php composer.phar update

Comment: при установке Composer-Setup.exe начал выдавать окно с надписью PHP Startup: Unable to load dynemic library'/usr/local/php/ext\php_mysql.dll' - не найден указанный путь и еще тоже самое с другими библиотеками, хотя все они есть в папке C:\WebServers\usr\local\php5\ext Может не тот путь указал для php.exe ?

Comment: А PHP у вас какой версии? В php.ini пути к расширениям правильно указаны? (обратите внимание на слеши в путях) У вас должно быть что-то вроде:
extension_dir = "C:/WebServers/usr/local/php5/ext/"

Comment: php версия 5.3.13. Путь один нашел extension_dir = "/usr/local/php5/ext" и все. Все остальное что ли самому прописывать?

Comment: Пропишите явно: extension_dir = "C:/WebServers/usr/local/php5/ext/"
должно заработать

Comment: прописал путь. Установил пакет расширений и при запуске denwer начал выдавать ошибку MSVCR71.dll не найден, нажимаю ОК, вылазит другое окошко с сообщением unable to load dynamic library php_interbase.dll.
MSVCR71.dll в system32 есть, я проверил, php_interbase.dll в папке ext тоже есть. Я за комментировал строку php_interbase.dll в php.ini, ошибок при запуске нет. Но при вводе в командной строке php composer.phar update выводится в консоли Could not open input file: composer.phar. Для чего вообще этот идиотизм с этим composer сделали???

Comment: > Для чего вообще этот идиотизм с этим composer сделали???
<pre>
Поспешный вывод. Не спешите. Для тех, кто умеет с ним обращаться, это очень полезный инструмент. Некоторые работодатели прямо в список требований пишут: "владение composer". Если есть интерес, рекомендую погрузиться.
По теме: </pre>
 > вылазит другое окошко с сообщением unable to load dynamic library php_interbase.dll

Это может означать, что эта версия библиотеки не поддерживается.

Comment: > Но при вводе в командной строке php composer.phar update выводится в консоли Could not open input file: composer.phar

А вы перешли в директорию, где у вас лежит composer.phar? Там же рядом у вас должен лежать composer.json - в нем вы указываете все необходимые вам библиотеки и расширения. Команда php composer.phar update в каталоге с приложением скачивает и обновляет все указанные в composer.json библиотеки. Команда php composer.phar install - устанавливает их куда нужно.

Comment: я ввел в консоли cd c:\WebServers\home\localhost\www\fuelphp\
затем php composer.phar update и получил:
http://webfile.ru/c65105f4157bdad4fff3f7190fd923fc

MSVCR71.dll в system32 присутствует!